# How to find sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n(2n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

$$\frac{1}{1 \times3} + \frac{1}{2\times5}+\frac{1}{3\times7} + \frac{1}{4\times9}+\cdots $$

How to find sum of this series?

I tried this: its $n$th term will be = $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{2n+1}$; after that  I am not able to solve this.

Answer (score 8):

First, we can rewrite the partial sum as an integral
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(2n+1)} = 2\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)
= 2\sum_{n=1}^N \int_0^1 (z^{2n-1} - z^{2n}) dz\\
= 2 \int_0^1 z(1-z)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} z^{2n}\right) dz
= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{z}{1+z}( 1 - z^{2N} ) dz
$$
Notice the $N$ dependence piece on RHS can be bounded from above
$$\left| 2 \int_0^1 \frac{z}{1+z} z^{2N} dz \right|
< 2 \int_0^1 z^{2N} dz = \frac{2}{2N+1} \to 0 
\quad\text{ as }\quad N \to \infty
$$
We have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n+1)} 
=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(2n+1)} 
= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{z}{1+z} dz = 2 (1 - \log 2)$$

Comment: @archillehui Could you explain why the integral of $N$ dependent term vanishing to $0$ implies that you can ignore the term when taking the limit? Or suggest to me where I can read more?

Comment: @crystal_math It is basically definition chasing. If $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n = L + b_N$, then $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n - L\right| = |b_N|$. If $\lim_{N\to \infty} |b_N| = 0$, then forall $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N'$ such that $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N a_n - L\right| = |b_N| < \epsilon$ whenever $N > N'$. Compare this with the definition of $\sum_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$....

Answer (score 6):

The sum can be found using our [favourite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615281/if-sum-n-1-infty-6-over-nn3-converges-find-its-sum/2615486#2615486) alternative method of converting the sum into a double integral.

Noting that
$$\int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^1 y^{2n} \, dy = \frac{1}{2n + 1},$$
the sum can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n (2n + 1)} &= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} y^{2n} \, dx dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty x^{n - 1} y^{2n} \, dx dy \tag1 \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (xy^2)^n \, dx dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{xy^2}{1 - xy^2} \, dx dy \tag2\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y^2}{1 - xy^2} \, dx dy\\
&= -\int_0^1 \ln (1 - xy^2) \Big{|}_0^1 \, dy\\
&= - \int_0^1 \ln (1 - y^2) \, dy\\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{y(1 - y)}{1 - y^2} \, dy \tag3\\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{y}{1 + y} \, dy\\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{(1 + y) - 1}{1 + y} \, dy\\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \left (1 - \frac{1}{1 + y} \right ) \, dy\\
&= 2 \left [y - \ln (1 + y) \right ]_0^1\\
&= 2 (1 - \ln 2).
\end{align*}

**Explanation**

(1) Changing the summation with the double integration.

(2) Summing the series which is geometric.

(3) Integrating by parts.

Comment: Today I've learnt something new it's just because of you! Thanks! for such a (all) wonderful answers !

Comment: I have recently summed a number of convergent series by first converting them to a double (or sometimes triple) integral, and as you have seen, is one of my favourite ways to solve such problems.

Comment: @omegadot why can you switch the infinite sum and the integrals? Dominant convergence?

Comment: @crystal_math If $f_n(x,y) = x^{n - 1}y^{2n}$, since $f_n(x,y) \geqslant 0$ for all $x,y \in (0,1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by Tonelli's theorem interchanging the order of the summation with the integration is permissible.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}= \frac 1n-\frac{2}{2n+1}=2\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$

Hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n(2n+1)} =2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)= 2\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\right)=\color{red}{ 2(1-\ln 2)} $$

since $${\displaystyle \ln(1+x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}x^{n}=x-{\frac {x^{2}}{2}}+{\frac {x^{3}}{3}}-\cdots ,}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{ n(2n+1)}$. Then we have $$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{ n}=-\log(1-x^2).$$ Hence since f(0)=0, the sum is equal to
\begin{align}
s&=-\int_0^1\log(1-x^2)dx\\
&=-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos x) \cos x dx\\
&=-2I
\end{align}
To solve this integral, $I$, note first that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x) \cos x dx=-1$. Thus
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cos x) \cos x dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x) \cos x dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x) \cos x dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\log(\cot x) \cos x dx-1\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\Big(\log(\cot x) \cos x+\sec x -\sec x \Big)dx-1\\
&=\lim_{a\to \pi/2}\int_0^{a}\Big(\log(\cot x) \cos x-\sec x +\sec x \Big)dx-1\\
&=\lim_{a\to \pi/2}\Big(\log(\cot x) \sin x +\log [\cos \frac x2 + \sin \frac x2]-\log [\cos \frac x2 -\sin \frac x2] \Big)-1\\
&=\log2-1
\end{align}

... I should still add more ...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(2n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\int_0^1 x^{2n}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n}dx=-\int_0^1\ln(1-x^2)dx$$

$$=-\underbrace{\int_0^1\ln(1-x)dx}_{1-x=y}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\ln(1+x)dx}_{1+x=y}=-\int_0^2\ln(y)dy$$

$$=y-y\ln(y)|_0^2=2-2\ln(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your series can be written as 
$$
    \frac{H_{x}}{2x} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k\cdot2(k+x)}\, ,
$$
with $x=\frac12$. $H_{\frac12}$ is given here: [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).
$$
    H_{\frac{1}{2}} = 2 -2\ln{2},
$$
which is your result...