# Prove that $-2\log(2) = -2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, digamma-function

How to prove that

$$
-2\log(2) = -2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}
$$

I know that this sum is equal to $\phi(1/2)+\gamma$ where $\phi(x)$ is the digamma function and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, but I want to evaluate the sum without knowing it.

Comment: That's actually $-2\log2$.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I fixed it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find sum of the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n(2n+1)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334870/how-to-find-sum-of-the-infinite-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-n2n1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}=\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}.$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n(2n+1)}
=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2n}-\frac1{2n+1}\right)
=2\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{m}.$$
Of course,
$$\log2=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{m}.$$

Comment: Thanks al lot:)

Comment: @Alex make sure to tick this as an answer :) $\ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 2):

Or you can prove forward:
$$\begin{align}-2\ln2=
&-2\left(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\cdots\right)=\\ 
&-2\left(1-\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}-\frac{1}{4\cdot 5}-\cdots\right)=\\
&-2\left(1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n\cdot (2n+1)}\right)=\\
&-2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2n+1)}.\end{align}$$